# Where do deleted files go in SVN?

Tags: svn, restore, revert

I just removed some files by using `svn --force delete path/folder copy`. However, the space between `folder` and `copy` made it think it had to delete multiple things, so now it removed my original folder.

I hadn't versioned my original folder yet, so all changes are gone. Luckily, I didn't change a lot in that specific folder, so this is mostly for future use if I end up doing the same stupid thing: How do I revert or restore files that have not been committed before? Where do I find these files? They did not get moved to my trash can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are deleted, pure and simple.  Unfortunately, the [documentation for the `delete` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html) only says this:

> Files (and directories that have not been committed) are immediately removed from the working copy unless the `--keep-local` option is given.

For proof, we have to look waaaay down in the SVN source, where [svn_io_remove_file2](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/io.c) eventually calls [apr_file_remove](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__file__io.html#ga211c40be82f8bf8b8d7dce5afca5500b), which:

- if you're on Windows [invokes](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk/file_io/win32/open.c) [DeleteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx).  This method just deletes the file; if the programmers wanted to send it to the Recycle Bin, they'd instead have to use [SHFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) and pass it the `FOF_ALLOWUNDO` flag.
- if you're on *nix (includes Mac OS), [invokes](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk/file_io/unix/open.c) [unlink](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink), which does the following:

  > ... the file is deleted and the space it was using is made available for reuse

*Note: I'd do a deeper link to points in the code, but the web-accessible SVN and APR repositories don't allow line-level linking :(*

Comment: Ok, so it's lost. Thanks for the answer, will try to keep my head on my body next time I delete copies :D

Comment: Yeah, personally I don't think `svn delete` should remove non-committed files from your disk; too many people I think will assume it will just "unschedule" it for addition.

Comment: I would really default to move it to the trash can. Might make an alias for that, to prevent idiocy to take over.